# Azure self-signed certificate on Key vault

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault, self-signed-certificate

Can you create a self-signed certificate on the Azure Key Vault?
Can the Azure Key vault be your PKI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , you can create `self-signed certificate` from ***Azure Key Vault***. To create a ***Self Signed certificate*** you can follow this ***[`Microsoft Documention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/quick-create-portal)***.

In the `Type of Certificate Authority` you can select `Self-Signed Certificate` as shown below:

[image]

You can also refer this ***[Blog](https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/generating-self-signed-certificate-with-keyvalt-and-enable-to-access-it-from-a-function-app-a121f6609b37)*** by ***Tsuyoshi Ushio*** for more details.

---

For the second part also its true that ***Azure Key Vault*** can be used or is used as a ***serverless/lightweight PKI***.

You will need to activate ***Managed HSM*** service on `Azure Key Vault` to use the functionality. You can follow this ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/overview)*** for more details on the same .